# Google Places API query only returning list of hotels, am I missing something here?

Tags: json, google-maps, google-api, google-places-api

So I'm working on a project in C# involving queries to Google Places API and I want to get back a list of ALL businesses in a selected area around a certain location. But for some reason I am only receiving Hotels. Even though I don't specify that as the only type. Here is my search query URL (obviously the API key is left out for privacy):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=51.221776328824,6.79015159606934&radius=500&key=ABCDEFGHIJKLMOP

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that the place results are sorted by **prominence** by default which means that ranking will favor prominent places within the specified area.

As noted in the Places API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests),

> Prominence can be affected by a place's ranking in Google's index,
> global popularity, and other factors.

You can try to use **rankby=distance** to get different results.

> This option biases search results in ascending order by their distance
> from the specified location. When distance is specified, one or more
> of keyword, name, or type is required.

Note that you must not include **radius** parameter if you want to use the **rankby** param.